# How do I get the text value of an input using only function components in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import Layout from "components/Layout"
import { useState } from "react";

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_API_URL}/kana-terms/all`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return {props: {data}}
}

function checkAnswer(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        console.log("Enter key was pressed");
    }
}

export default function Hiragana(props) {
    const [remainingTerms, setRemainingTerms] = useState(props.data);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>Hiragana</h1>
            <div className="bg-light border w-100">
                <h2>{remainingTerms[0].hiraganaText}</h2>
                <input type="text" onKeyUp={(event) => {checkAnswer(event, )}} />
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

I want to pass the text value of the `<input>` element to the `checkAnswer()` function.

How do I do that in React using only function components?

All the answers I can find through Google use class components.

I'm also using Next.js... if that matters.

Comment: You can get the text value from the event via `event.target.value`.

Answer (score 4):

Put the input value into state, then pass the stateful value into the `checkAnswer` call:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
```

and

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={value}
    onChange={e => { setValue(e.currentTarget.value); }}
    onKeyUp={(event) => {checkAnswer(event, value)}}
/>
```

Comment: What if you don't want to use the onChange? Browsers auto fill inputs so their isn't actually an on change to setState. How would you get values from inputs without using onChange?